# Vue.js & vuex - Reset a form to current state

Tags: vuejs2, vuex

I have a form in one of my components that I'm initially populating by cloning a piece of state using:

```
created () {
  this.currentUser = Object.assign({}, this.$store.getters.user)
}
```

I want to add a button to the form that enables the user to reset it back to it's initial value after they have made changes.

I've tried to do this by adding a function to a button like so:

```
methods: {
  cancelChanges () {
    this.currentUser = Object.assign({}, this.$store.getters.user)
  }
}
```

However, this isn't working. What's the correct way to do this?

Codepen here - https://codepen.io/stockzy/pen/xPGYXN?editors=1010#0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I figured it out (with a little help).

I was binding my data to the store, instead of copying a new instance to the component. This fixed it:

```
created () {
  this.currentUser = Object.assign({}, JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.$store.getters.user)))
}
```

and the same for the button:

```
cancelChanges () {
  this.currentUser = Object.assign({}, JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.$store.getters.user)))
}
```